# Как в C вывести аргумент функции, написанной на GNU Assembler (синтаксис AT&T)?

Tags: c, ассемблер, gcc, стек, gnu-assembler

Есть задача – написать программу из двух модулей: один на C, второй на ассемблере. Все источники единогласно утверждают, что аргументы в функцию, написанную на ассемблере, передаются через стек. Пытаясь проверить это, хочу сделать простенькую программу, которая хотя бы выводила бы первый аргумент функции, принимающей два аргумента. Вот код:

```cpp
// c_module.c

#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

extern int summ(int x, int y);

int main()
{

    int x = summ(5,6);

    printf("%d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

```assembler
// asm_module.s

.text

.globl summ
.type summ, @function

summ:
    push %bp

    movq %rsp, %rbp
    movl 4(%rbp), %eax

    pop %bp

    ret
```

Выводит большое число, точно не 5. Пробовал вместо 4 в ассемблерном коде подставлять другие числа, т.е. брать другие части из стека, толку нет. Числа разные, но это всё равно не 5. Пробовал смотреть стек с помощью GDB сразу после вызова ассемблерной функции – тоже ноль результата, даже через отладчик я не нашёл аргумент в стеке.

Компилятор gcc, делаю всё на ОС KUbuntu.

Вопрос: где же всё-таки прячется этот первый аргумент и как его оттуда наконец достать и возвратить модулю С?

Comment: @AlexF спасибо, попробую.

Comment: @AlexF первое не сработало. Если я не ошибаюсь, extern "C" используется для C++, я же пишу на чистом  C.

Comment: @AlexF глупо с моей стороны, но ни `push %rbp`, ни `pushq %rbp` не сработало.

Comment: @AlexF вот что дало `disas`: `0x0000000000001144 <main+0>: endbr64 
   0x0000000000001148 <main+4>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000001149 <main+5>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000000000114c <main+8>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
` по-моему маловато

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, из-за того, что система x64, аргументы функции передаются через регистры. В частности, в данном конкретном случае, первый аргумент был передан в регистр `%edi`, второй – в `%esi`.

Таким образом, рабочий ассемблерный код примет следующий вид:

```
// asm_module.s 
.text 

.globl summ 
.type summ, @function 
summ: 
    push %bp 
    movq %rsp, %rbp 
    movl %edi, %eax 
    pop %bp 
    ret
```

По всей видимости, в системах x86 аргументы передаются, как и ожидалось, через стек.

Comment: Передача нескольких первых параметров через регистры это как раз по соглашению о связях для 64-бит систем. Через стек параметры передаются в 32-бит

Comment: @avp спасибо, я исправлю это в своём ответе

Comment: Можете еще ознакомиться с [этой статьей](https://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf)

Comment: Если интересно, то в ARM (aarch64) регистры используются [так](https://developer.arm.com/docs/den0024/a/the-abi-for-arm-64-bit-architecture/register-use-in-the-aarch64-procedure-call-standard/parameters-in-general-purpose-registers)